# How to fix "The specified resource does not exist. HTTP Status Code: 404" Error while using Start-AzStorageFileCopy

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage, azure-powershell

I'm trying to copy files from one file directory in Azure Storage Explorer to a  sub-directory of the source files directory.

I initially wanted to use AZcopy to copy the files over, but Azcopy doesnt support copying files to a sub-directory.

So now I'm going the Powershell route, using Start-AzStorageFileCopy cmdlet.

Below is my full script

```
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "store1" -SasToken "? 
sv=2015-12-11&si=aaa-15D97F9B09D&sr=s&sig=xxx"

# Since the file name has date, you can specify which date to be deleted.
# In this sample, we try to delete the files' name contains previous 
datemonth string eg. "201901"

$pattern =[datetime]::Today.AddMonths(-2).ToString('yyyyMM')
$ShareName = "aaa"
$SourcePath = "Test/Temp_Clean_up_test_Folder"
$ArchivePath = "Test/Temp_Clean_up_test_Folder/Archive/"+        
[datetime]::Today.AddMonths(-2).ToString('yyyyMM')


Get-AzStorageFile -ShareName "aaa" -Path "Test/Temp_Clean_up_test_Folder" - 
Context $context | Get-AzStorageFile | where {($_.GetType().Name -eq 
"CloudFile") -and ($_.Name -like "*$pattern*")} | Start-AzStorageFileCopy - 
DestFilePath $ArchivePath -DestShareName "aaa" -SrcFile {$_} -DestContext 
$Context
```

I expect the files to copy over, but I receive the following error.

> Start-AzStorageFileCopy : The specified resource does not exist. HTTP Status >Code: 404 - HTTP Error Message: The specified resource does not exist.
>   At line:18 char:201
>   + ... ttern*")} | Start-AzStorageFileCopy -DestFilePath $ArchivePath -DestS >...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>      + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Start-AzStorageFileCopy], >StorageException
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : >StorageException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.File.Cmdlet.StartAzur>eStorageFileCopyCommand
>
> Start-AzStorageFileCopy : The specified resource does not exist. HTTP Status >Code: 404 - HTTP Error Message: The specified resource does not exist.
>   At line:18 char:201
>   + ... ttern*")} | Start-AzStorageFileCopy -DestFilePath $ArchivePath -DestS >...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>      + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Start-AzStorageFileCopy], >StorageException
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : >StorageException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.File.Cmdlet.StartAzur>eStorageFileCopyCommand

NOTES:

The Destination directory already exists.

The Source files Exist (I tested the output before I use Start-azStorageFileCopy Cmdlet)

I added

```
-DefaultProfile $Context
```

to the end of the script, hoping this would solve the issue, but it returned the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following code:

```
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "xxx" -SasToken "xxx"

$pattern =[datetime]::Today.AddMonths(-2).ToString('yyyyMM')
$sharename = "aaa"
$sourcepath = "Test/Temp_Clean_up_test_Folder"
$archivepath = "Test/Temp_Clean_up_test_Folder/Archive/"+[datetime]::Today.AddMonths(-2).ToString('yyyyMM')

# add the following code to create the archive directory, if it does not exist.
# New-AzStorageDirectory -Context $context -ShareName $sharename -Path $archivepath

 $files = Get-AzStorageFile -ShareName $sharename -Path $sourcepath -Context $context | Get-AzStorageFile | where {($_.GetType().Name -eq "CloudFile") -and ($_.Name -like "*$pattern*")}

 foreach($s1 in $files){ 

 Start-AzStorageFileCopy -SrcShareName $sharename -SrcFilePath (join-path $sourcepath $s1.name) -DestShareName $sharename -DestFilePath (join-path $archivepath $s1.name) -Context $context
}
```

Please note that make sure the archivepath exists before copy to it. if it does not exists, you can use the following code to create it:

```
New-AzStorageDirectory -Context $context -ShareName $sharename -Path $archivepath
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Appreciate your help.

Comment: @IvanYang; Thank you very much for your code. It works, except it does not copy files recursively.

Comment: Is there any way to check and create achieve path only if it does not exists ?

Comment: @sblive, yes, you can. first, you can get a fileshare by using this code: `$s = Get-AzStorageShare -Name $share_name`. then use `$s.ShareClient.GetDirectoryClient("bbb/ccc").Exists()` to check if the path exists. at last use this code to create if not exists `$s.ShareClient.GetDirectoryClient("bbb/ccc").Create()`.

Comment: @IvanYang I am using below lines of code 
`$s= Get-AzStorageShare -Context $ctx -Name $fileShareName Write-Host $s.ShareClient.GetDirectoryClient($folderPath).Exists()`

which results into ##[error]Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @sblive, so it's ok now, or you have other issues?

Comment: @IvanYang No. Why it is resulting into error. It should print either true/false.

Comment: @sblive, just use this code: `$s= Get-AzStorageShare -Context $ctx -Name $fileShareName`, then `$s.ShareClient.GetDirectoryClient("bbb/cccdd").CreateIfNotExists()`. by using this code, it will automatically determine if the path exists or not, and create it if not exist.